# How to Enable iterative calculation in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, openpyxl

is this way to enable iterative calculation Programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.sheet_view.showGridLines = False
ws1.title = "UserInputs"
set_border(ws1, "A1:D1")

# enable Iterative Calculation
wb.calculation.iterate=1
wb.calculation.iterateCount=50
wb.calculation.iterateDelta=0.05
# -----
wb.save('web_panel/files/excel/' + 'vignesh.xlsx')
wb.close()
print('Success')
```

[Offical Openpyxl documention](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.properties.html#openpyxl.workbook.properties.CalcProperties.iterate)